# Reconnect to Ubisoft servers

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

From time to time, my PS3 loses connection to the Ubisoft servers.

Normally, I wouldn't care about it too much, but I really do enjoy using my tablet as a map thanks to the [Assassin’s Creed® IV Companion app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubisoft.assassin.blackflag), which is pretty much useless when the game is no longer online.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a way to reconnect to the servers, except by quitting the game to the main menu and starting Uplay.

How can I reconnect to the Ubisoft servers without quitting my current game session? Is it even possible? Uplay takes ages to load after all...

Comment: The unreliability of the connections to the server is a real pain in the neck. The companion app was a reason to bring my purchase of a tablet forward but given that 50% of the time Ubi servers seem offline it seems the app is more effort than its worth. :(

Comment: @Chris And whenever it's not the Ubisoft servers failing me, it's the PSN server or my PS3 getting `DNS error`s... It really is a pain to deal with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you get access to *Kenway's Fleet* starting with sequence 4, you can manually log in to the Ubisoft servers by accessing your fleet in the *Captain's Quarters* on the *Slackjaw*. That's because the fleet minigame is online only.

This is the closest I've found to logging in the Ubisoft servers, without having to quit the game and start Uplay.

Comment: I think it may also retry on its own from time to time. I've certainly noticed my online icon lit up when it wasn't previously without going to Kenway's Fleet.